# Convert a class to a Json Object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a class DraftForm :

```
public class DraftForm 
{
    public string Json { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string DraftNumber { get; set; }
    public string DraftName{ get; set; }
}
```

In this method I want to return a Json of the DraftForm class :

```
public Object GetAllDraftDossier()
{
    var draftDossiers = _context.DraftForms
        .Where(x=> x.DraftName== "Repairer")
        .ToList();
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        draftDossiers, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        }
    );
    return json;
}
```

The controller :

```
[Route("repair/UnfinishedDossiers")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllDraftDossier()
    {
        var draftDossier = _dossierRepairRepository.GetAllDraftDossier();
        return Ok(draftDossier);
    }
```

In postman it returns a string and not a json ! Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you show the controller code? Which version of ASP are you using? Why does your method return an object instead of a string?

Comment: Because I want it to return a Json object and not a string

Comment: You don't need to serialize to JSON in `GetAllDraftDossier`. Return non-serialized result from the `GetAllDraftDossier` controller method and let the framework serialize the result for you.

Comment: How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your repository method to:

```
public IList<DraftForm> GetAllDraftDossier()
{
    return _context.DraftForms
        .Where(x=> x.DraftName== "Repairer")
        .ToList();
}
```

The controller will then return `IList<DraftForm>` as the `IHttpActionResult` and the framework will serialize this to JSON for you.

Comment: You don't need ToList, returning an IEnumerable will do the same thing

Comment: @Liam strictly speaking, you are correct and you don't need the `ToList()`. But if you'd remove it, the query would be executed at the time of the serialization by the framework which is often not prefered. But that's a different discussion which falls out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I think my question was not cleared :/ I tried your solution and my problem is that the property 'json' in the DraftForm class always display like that in postman ` "json": "{\"generalInfo\":{\"client\":{\"id\":\"ec885a89-4458-4c0a-be12-21657a5ff8e4\",\"name\":\"Ab Lekdetectie\"},\"activity\":{\"code\":\"Investigation\",\"name` I want to convert it in Json type

Comment: So your question is about the `DraftForm.Json` property specifically? Why is this a string and not an object? Please add more details to your question including the JSON output you have now and the output you want to have.